# iOS Model View Controller Design Pattern

Tags: ios

How do I exactly implement MVC design pattern to my code?

1. Controller -> Call Rest Service with RestKit.
2. Bind the JSON to a Object --> Which is A model
3. Controller display bunch of data based on the model.

Now where do I implement View?
Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are using `UIViewController`, that will have a "View" as well as a "Controller".

Comment: A good starting point: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ViewController should observe changes to the model and update it's view hierarchy, whose root is `self.view`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // observe the model, via kvo, or subscribe to notification, or make self == somebody's delegate, etc.
}

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender {
    // change the model  [self.model change]
    // or start a web request with self as delegate
}

// called by kvo or delegate or notification or [self modelDidChange];

- (void)modelDidChange {
    // update self.view or children viewWithTag: or outlets setup to subviews
}
```